# This assembly looks accessible. JavaScript isn't able to find it

Tags: javascript, .net, com, com-interop, .net-assembly

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Security;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using System.Collections;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

[assembly: AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers]
namespace Whatever
{
    [
        Guid("AD3EE0B2-4C9F-441B-8E6F-0D1223354EBD"),
        InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual),
        ComVisible(true)
    ]

    public interface ISetup
    {
        [DispId(1)]
        string Hello();

        [DispId(2)]
        int ShowDialog(string msg);
    };

    [
        Guid("81F44339-C03D-444F-95AD-3E86CF8FA514"),
        ProgId("Whatever.CSetup"),

        ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None),

        ComDefaultInterface(typeof(ISetup)),
        ComVisible(true)
    ]

    public class CSetup : ISetup
    {
        #region [ISetup implementation]

        [ZoneIdentityPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Zone = SecurityZone.Intranet)]
        public string Hello()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hello world.");
            return "Hello from CSetup object";
        }

        public int ShowDialog(string msg)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(msg, "");
            return 0;
        }
        #endregion
    };
}
```

When I used `regasm /codebase /tlb /verbose Whatever.dll` I got this feedback:

```
Microsoft (R) .NET Framework Assembly Registration Utility 4.0.30319.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 1998-2004.  All rights reserved.

Types registered successfully
Type 'N' exported.
Type 'N' exported.
Assembly exported to 'C:\Users\Whoever\Whatever.tlb', and the type lib
rary was registered successfully
```

Which is great aside from not knowing what Type 'N' exported means, but the assembly does show up in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\ as "Whatever.CSetup"

If I launch a browser to the site that contains the JavaScript (reproduced below) that doesn't yet recognize the .NET assembly method being problematically invoked, I can see, in MSIE menu Tools!Internet Options!Programs!Manage add-ons!Toolbars and Extensions, that "Whatever.CSetup" appears alongside a few other add-ons in the Names column, and the Status column reports it as Enabled.  (Although Load Time and Navigation Time columns for it show nothing--but neither do Send to Bluetooth Device or a few others.)

The JavaScript:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" > 

<html>
  <head>
    <title>WebForm1</title>
    <meta name="GENERATOR" Content="Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 7.1">
    <meta name="CODE_LANGUAGE" Content="C#">
    <meta name=vs_defaultClientScript content="JavaScript">
    <meta name=vs_targetSchema content="http://schemas.microsoft.com/intellisense/ie5">
  </head>
  <body onload="OpenActiveX()">

  <!-- Our activeX object -->
  <OBJECT id="Whatever.CSetup" name=”Whatever.CSetup" classid="clsid:81F44339-C03D-444F-95AD-3E86CF8FA514" VIEWASTEXT codebase="Whatever.CSetup"></OBJECT>  

  <!-- Attaching to an ActiveX event-->
<script language="javascript">
           function OurActiveX::OnClose(redirectionUrl)
       {
        alert(redirectionUrl);   <!-- http://otherwebsite.com should be returned-->
                    //window.location = redirectionUrl;
           }
</script>


<script language="javascript">
    //Passing parameters to ActiveX object and starting application
function OpenActiveX()
{
    try
    {
//      document.OurActiveX.MyParam = "Hi I am here." //Passing parameter to the ActiveX
        document.Whatever.CSetup.Open(); //Running method from activeX
    }
    catch(Err)
    {
        alert(Err.description);
    }
}   
</script>
 </body>
</html>
```

When I go to the page, I get "Unable to get value of the property Whatever.CSetup': object is null or undefined"

1. I know this:  if I test by changing the CLSID in the JavaScript, going to the page will not trigger anything at all.  If I change it back, I get that error message.
2. I can't be certain about what I'm supplying into the `<OBJECT id="Whatever.CSetup" name=”Whatever.CSetup" classid="clsid:81F44339-C03D-444F-95AD-3E86CF8FA514" VIEWASTEXT codebase="Whatever.CSetup"></OBJECT>` other than to venture that I have the right value in the CLSID field.  Anything else, those for "id" or "name" or "codebase," I don't know.
3. I have no idea whether I'm calling the assembly class method correctly near the bottom of the js.

A JavaScript similar to this is reputed to be able to invoke a .NET assembly method.  There are three sites that confirm it to be possible:

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/38890-activex-with-c#
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24089/Create-ActiveX-in-NET-Step-by-Step
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1265/COM-IDs-Registry-keys-in-a-nutshell

Thank you for any help.